# index.php suddenly appears in my Nginx sites-available directory

Tags: server, php, nginx

I never created a file named `index.php` anywhere but such file suddenly appears in my Nginx `sites-available` directory.

I felt no change in the system's behavior. I already destroyed that virtual machine so I can't bring the file content though it was quite long (~300 lines).

It was likely created by Nginx, but why would it?

Answer (score 3):

NGINX doesn't create files except its own logfiles (this excludes file uploads for a website, which would end up in the site docroot, not anywhere else, but even then that's not NGINX doing things itself, that's some website being the one really to do the upload/creation of the file).  It's likely that you accidentally did `nano` or `touch` or something which created the `index.php` file incorrectly in that directory.

NGINX doesn't create random files inside its own configuration directories.  Rule out any user error you or any other authorized users have done first.